# Mysql повторные записи

Tags: mysql, relation, повторы

Добрый день!
При выполнении следующего запроса извлекаются повторные записи, но в таблице просто не может быть столько записей, что не так:

```sql
SELECT
t1.hotel_name AS Hotel,
t2.city_name AS City,
t1.stars AS Stars,
t1.average AS Rating,
t1.latitude AS Latitude,
t1.longitude AS Longitude,
t1.address AS Address,
t1.photo AS Photos,
t1.hightlights AS Hightlights,
t1.description AS Description,
t1.url AS Url,
t3.partner_name AS BP,
t4.low AS BL,
t4.hight AS BH
FROM
hotels AS  t1, cities AS t2, partners AS t3, prices AS t4
WHERE t2.city_name='$data' LIMIT 20";
```

Где `$data` название города.

Таблицы связанные:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `cities`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_cities_countries` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `countries` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `hotels`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_hotels_cities` FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) REFERENCES `cities` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `partners_hotels`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_partners_hotels_partners` FOREIGN KEY (`partner_id`) REFERENCES `partners` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `partners_hotels`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_partners_hotels_hotels` FOREIGN KEY (`hotel_id`) REFERENCES `hotels` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `prices`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_prices_hotels` FOREIGN KEY (`hotel_id`) REFERENCES `hotels` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `prices`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_prices_partners` FOREIGN KEY (`partner_id`) REFERENCES `partners_hotels` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Когда использую вместе с `DISTINCT` повторов нету, но записи не соответствуют выборке.
Сами таблицы:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `countries` (
    `id` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `country_code` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    `country_name` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cities` (
    `id` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `country_id` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `city_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `country_id` (`country_id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hotels` (
    `id` MEDIUMINT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `city_id` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `hotel_name` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    `stars` FLOAT(2,1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `average` FLOAT(2,1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `latitude` DOUBLE(24,18) NOT NULL,
    `longitude` DOUBLE(24,18) NOT NULL,
    `address` TEXT(500) NOT NULL,
    `photo` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `hightlights` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    `description` TEXT(4000) NOT NULL,
    `rooms` SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `url` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `city_id` (`city_id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `partners` (
    `id` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `partner_name` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `partners_hotels` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `hotel_id` MEDIUMINT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `partner_id` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `hotel_id` (`hotel_id`),
     KEY `partner_id` (`partner_id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prices` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `hotel_id` MEDIUMINT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `partner_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `low` FLOAT(8, 2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `hight` FLOAT(8, 2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `currency` VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `hotel_id` (`hotel_id`),
     KEY `partner_id` (`partner_id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: расшифруйте фразу `но в таблице просто не может быть столько записей`

Comment: Создайте пример своих данных с неправильным результатом на http://sqlfiddle.com/ и добавьте ссылку в вопрос.

Comment: все работает так, как написано. не указав связи, вы получили декартово произведение. ЗЫ Используйте ANSI синтаксис для join'ов

Comment: @Ella Svetlaya не может быть несколько отелей с одинаковыми названиями.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov Можете написать как должен выглядеть запрос?

Comment: Про декартово произведение почитайте. Этот запрос (без учёта limit) будет возвращать примерно count(t1) * 1 * count(t3) * count(t4) = очень много записей. В ответе написали, как стоит записать запрос, но всё равно почитайте.

Answer (score 1):

Без примера данных это лишь пример запроса. Запрос будет выглядеть примерно так.

```
SELECT
  h.*, pa.*, pr.* c.* -- конкретные поля скипнуты
FROM hotels AS h 
  join cities AS c on h.city_id = c.id
  join prices AS pr on pr.hotel_id = h.id
  join partners AS pa on pa.id = pr.partner_id and pa.hotel_id = h.id
WHERE 
  c.city_name='$data' 
ORDER BY h.hotel_name
LIMIT 20
```

По виду запрос возвращает в каждой строке отель с ценами одного из партнеров в определенном городе, притом не больше 20. Т.е. записей будет столько, сколько партнеров предлагает свои услуги в каждом из отелей определенного города. Если есть три отеля и по два партнера для каждого отеля, значит в результате будет 6 записей.

N.B. Таблица `partners_hotels` выглядит избыточной, если у вас связи партнеров и так и отелей прописаны в `prices`. Либо `prices` должны ссылаться на `partners_hotels`...